# Get message if transaction roll back

Tags: spring, transactions

```
@Transactional
public User getUser(String username) {
return userDAO.getUser(username);
}
```

I am using spring @Transactional annotation in my project.Now if transaction is rolled back i want to catch a notification so that i can show it to the user.How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If the transaction fails, that indicates an exception was thrown. You will have to catch the Exception from the place (mostly the controller) where you are calling this method `public User getUser(String username)` and in the catch you can set some error code/ error message into the request and use it to display the message on UI.